# Eager loaded relationship giving wrong values

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel model 'Delegates' with a list of students doing training.
I also have 2 other Models/tables:

honorifics - Mr, Ms, Miss, etc. and

Countries - all the countries in the world

My Delegates model has 2 methods to link to the relationship tables:

```
    public function HonorificInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Honorific::class, 'ID', 'HonorificId');
    }
```

and

```
    public function NationalityInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Country::class, 'id', 'Nationality');
    }
```

My Delegates table has 2 records of relevance:
| id | HonorificId | FamilyName | ForeNames | Nationality |
| -- | ----------- | ---------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 16425 | NULL  | FamilyName1 | ForeNames1 | NULL |
| 16426 | 1     | FamilyName1 | ForeNames1 | 133  |

My Controller has this query:

```
$delegates = Delegate::with(['HonorificInfo.honorific', 'NationalityInfo.CountryName'])->where('ForeNames', 'Forenames1')->where('FamilyName', 'FamilyName1')->withTrashed()->get();
```

which gets the 2 records with the relationship tables.

debugging the data shows this:

```
$delegates=[{"id":16425,"HonorificId":null,"FamilyName":"FamilyName1","ForeNames":"Forename1","honorific_info":{"id":1,"honorific":"Mr"},"nationality_info":null},{"id":16426,"HonorificId":"1","FamilyName":"FamilyName1","ForeNames":"Forename1", "honorific_info":null,"nationality_info":{"id":133,"CountryName":"Malaysia"}}]
```

This is wrong. For record 16425, HonorificId is null so honorific_info should also be null - it is returning "Mr".

For record 16426, HonorificId is 1 so honorific_info should be Mr but the honorific_info relation data is null!

In my blade I have some debugging info which looks like this:

```
\Log::debug('delegates.edit2Dupes(): ' . $delegates[0]->id . ' = ' . $delegates[0]->HonorificId . ' = ' . $delegates[0]->HonorificInfo);
\Log::debug('delegates.edit2Dupes(): ' . $delegates[1]->id . ' = ' . $delegates[1]->HonorificId . ' = ' . $delegates[1]->HonorificInfo);
\Log::debug('delegates.edit2Dupes(): ' . $delegates[0]->id . ' = ' . $delegates[0]->Nationality . ' = ' . $delegates[0]->NationalityInfo);
\Log::debug('delegates.edit2Dupes(): ' . $delegates[1]->id . ' = ' . $delegates[1]->Nationality . ' = ' . $delegates[1]->NationalityInfo);
```

The debug info looks like this:

```
[2022-07-31 09:25:32] local.DEBUG: delegates.edit2Dupes(): 16425 =  = {"id":1,"honorific":"Mr"}  
[2022-07-31 09:25:32] local.DEBUG: delegates.edit2Dupes(): 16426 = 1 =   
[2022-07-31 09:25:32] local.DEBUG: delegates.edit2Dupes(): 16425 =  =   
[2022-07-31 09:25:32] local.DEBUG: delegates.edit2Dupes(): 16426 = 133 = {"id":133,"CountryName":"Malaysia"}
```

The Nationality info works perfectly - the first record has null Nationality & the 2nd record has Nationality of Malaysian.

I can't even see how this is possible! The tables are in SQL Server and they all have the correct primary keys & foreign keys. This is actually simplified and there are a lot more relationships in addition to Nationality such as country of birth, present country of abode, etc. Everything works perfectly apart from this Honorific and Honorific works fine in other parts of my code.

Comment: does `Honorific` model has `honorific` method?

Comment: Your Delegates model should BELONG TO the honorific and nationality models (not has one).  Of course this means it has foreign_id columns on the delegates table

Comment: `Honorific` model has an `honorific` field, not a method.  Snapey...I have to research further into that as both `Honorific` & `Nationality` use hasOne but `Nationality` works fine. I would have thought each `Delegate` has one `Nationality` (ignoring dual nationality as we only care about the nationality of the ID card presented) and each `Delegate` has one `Honorific`.  
If I don't use eager loading, this works fine which confuses me more.

Comment: 2 days to figure this out! I had "ID" instead of "id" in my `HonorificInfo()` method!